# Does pandoc support creation of markdown tables in its templates?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I am reading the pandoc manual nd if I am understanding this correctly, it supports usage of a template file and a YAML file that contains the variables to use in the templates.
It also says that the YAML supports any arbitrary objects (even lists). However, I want to ask if its possible to render markdown tables in the template using the YAML data.
The examples only show a simple key and value mapping.

---

**Edit:**
I created a testable.md file that contains this

```
---
table:
  caption: Cities
  headers: [city, population]
  rows:
    - [Berlin, '3,748,148']
    - [Tokyo, '13,839,910']
---

$table$

**Random Text**
```

and used this command to use the filter provided by tarleb:
`pandoc -f markdown -t docx --lua-filter=yaml_table.lua -o target.docx testtable.md`

However it seems that the output file still does not contain the table.
Am I missing something?

---

**Edit:**
I realized that the template file is specified differently from the input
It worked properly when I made testtable.md to only contain the following:

```
---
table:
  caption: Cities
  headers: [city, population]
  rows:
    - [Berlin, '3,748,148']
    - [Tokyo, '13,839,910']
---
```

And created a template file called markdowntmpl.md containing the following

```
$table$

**Random Text**
```

Then I used the following command:

```
pandoc -f markdown -t markdown --template=markdowntemplate.md --lua-filter=yaml_table.lua -o target.md testtable.md
```

Output:

```
  city     population
  -------- ------------
  Berlin   3,748,148
  Tokyo    13,839,910

  : Cities

**Random Text**
```

Then I can proceed to creating a docx document out of it.

Comment: If you can find a data type supported by YAML which holds tabular data, then you should be able to use that data to build a table. But I'm not aware of any YAML supported data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All elements representable in Markdown can also be put into metadata fields. The easiest way to insert complex elements is to use the newline-preserving YAML syntax for multiline strings. E.g.,

```
---
table: |
  | city   | population |
  |--------|------------|
  | Berlin |  3,748,148 |
  | Tokyo  | 13,839,910 |
---
```

This defines `table` as a metadata field containing a table.

---

There is no "native" YAML way of defining a table, but you can roll your own with a pandoc [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html).

Say one would like to define a table like this:

```
---
table:
  caption: Cities
  headers: [city, population]
  rows:
    - [Berlin, '3,748,148']
    - [Tokyo, '13,839,910']
---
```

Then it's possible to use the following filter to convert it into a pandoc table.

```lua
local List = require 'pandoc.List'

function repeated(item, times)
  local result = {}
  for i = 1, times do result[i] = item end
  return result
end

function to_table (tbl)
  if tbl.t ~= 'MetaMap' or not tbl.rows then
    return nil
  end

  -- Turn MetaInlines into blocks
  local to_blocks = function (x) return {pandoc.Plain(List:new(x))} end

  local headers = (List:new(tbl.headers)):map(to_blocks)
  local rows = List:new(tbl.rows):map(
    function (row) return List:new(row):map(to_blocks) end
  )
  local columns = #rows[1]
  local aligns = tbl.aligns or repeated(pandoc.AlignDefault, columns)
  local widths = tbl.widths or repeated(0, columns)
  return pandoc.Table(List:new(tbl.caption), aligns, widths, headers, rows)
end

function Meta (meta)
  for k, v in pairs(meta) do
      local success, result = pcall(to_table, v)
      if success and result then
        meta[k] = pandoc.MetaBlocks{result}
      end
  end
  return meta
end
```

Comment: That's neat. I was thinking of a YAML 2D Array

---
table: [[Name, Address],[Alice, Wonderland],[Batman, Gotham]]
---

I wonder if it is possible to render this as a table in markdown

Comment: ☝️There you go.

Comment: Thanks for the lua filter reference! I guess I need to study this first

Answer (score 2):

I have decided to answer as I had a similar problem & reading through  [this](https://github.com/jgm/doctemplates) has given a new perspective to me.

Basically, you can use something like `${table.rows[ & ]} \\` to render the table. In particular, this code should do it in your example:

```latex
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
  ${ for(table.rows) }
  ${ table.rows[ & ] }\\
  ${ endfor }
\end{tabular}
```

(adapt the `tabular` environment as needed).

The explanation is that the `for(table.rows)` clause will iterate through your yaml list (the dashes-defined one right under `rows` scope). Inside this `for` loop, you can reference to the item as (confusingly) `table.rows` (so, that would refer to the current row inside the loop). The syntax `table.rows[ & ]` instructs pandoc to expand said item (which itself is a list) using the separator  `&` .

So the expanded code will look like:

```latex
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
  Berlin & 3,748,148 \\
  Tokyo & 13,839,910 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Finally, to render the table with header and caption, simply do:

```latex
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
  ${ table.headers[ & ] }
  \midrule
  ${ for(table.rows) }
  ${ table.rows[ & ] }\\
  ${ endfor }
\end{tabular}
\caption{${ table.caption }}
```

No filters needed!

Comment: Note this is with pandoc version 2.17.1